# Connection between KMP prefix function and string matching automaton

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata, strings, searching

Let $A_P = (Q,\Sigma,\delta,0,\{m\})$ the *string matching automaton* for pattern $P \in \Sigma^m$, that is

- $Q = \{0,1,\dots,m\}$
- $\delta(q,a) = \sigma_P(P_{0,q}\cdot a)$ for all $q\in Q$ and $a\in \Sigma$

with $\sigma_P(w)$ the length of the longest prefix of $P$ that is a Suffix of $w$, that is

$\qquad \displaystyle \sigma_P(w) = \max \left\{k \in \mathbb{N}_0 \mid P_{0,k} \sqsupset w \right\}$.

Now, let $\pi$ the *prefix function* from the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), that is

$\qquad \displaystyle \pi_P(q)= \max \{k \mid k < q \wedge P_{0,k} \sqsupset P_{0,q}\}$.

As it turns out, one can use $\pi_P$ to compute $\delta$ quickly; the central observation is:

> Assume above notions and $a \in \Sigma$. For $q \in \{0,\dots,m\}$ with $q = m$ or $P_{q+1} \neq a$, it holds that
>
> $\qquad \displaystyle \delta(q,a) = \delta(\pi_P(q),a)$

But how can I prove this?

---

For reference, this is how you compute $\pi_P$:

```
m ← length[P ]
π[0] ← 0
k ← 0
for q ← 1 to m − 1 do
  while k > 0 and P [k + 1] =6 P [q] do
    k ← π[k]
    if P [k + 1] = P [q] then
       k ← k + 1
    end if
    π[q] ← k
 end while
end for

return π
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? What is the pattern? What precisely is the prefix function -- I didn't see a prefix function on the link you provided? Is the automaton deterministic or nondeterministic?

Comment: Isn't that the _definition_ of the KMP transition function?  You might find [these notes](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/2009/notes/10h-kmp.pdf) helpful (but see footnote 1).

Comment: I edited the question with the prefix function of KMP

Comment: So, your question is basically how to prove that the code above computes the prefix function of KMP.

Comment: My question is not to prove that the code above computes the prefix function, but i want to prove the first statement. I want to prove it by mathematical induction or contraddiction or any other kind of proof

Comment: Is this supposed to hold for any finite automaton? If so, how can $\delta$ sometimes take numbers? What is the state set? Or is the automaton a linear chain that accepts $P$?

Comment: I checked "my" lecture notes and found the statement. The question was heavily underspecified; I have edited to compensate.

Comment: @Raphael: I find the edited question _much_ less readable.

Comment: @JeffE: Too bad. At least it contains all necessary information now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that by definition

- $\delta(q,a) = \sigma_P(P_{0,q}\cdot a) =: s_1$ and
- $\delta(\pi_P(q),a) = \sigma_P(P_{0,\pi_P(q)}\cdot a) =: s_2$.

Let us investigate $s_1$ and $s_2$ in a sketch:

[image: sketch]
<sup>[[source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/cs_1669.tikz)]</sup>

Now assume $s_2 > s_1$; this contradicts the maximal choice of $s_1$ directly. If we assume $s_1 > s_2$ we contradict the fact that *both* $s_2$ and $\pi_P(q)$ are chosen maximally, in particular because $\pi_P(q) \geq s_1 - 1$. As both cases cases lead to contradictions $s_1=s_2$ holds, q.e.d.

---

*As requested, a more elaborate version of the proof:*

Now we have to show $s_1=s_2$; we do this by showing that the opposite leads to contradictions.

- Assume $s_2 > s_1$. Note that $P_{0,s_2} \sqsupset P_{0,q}\cdot a$ because $P_{0,s_2} \sqsupset P_{0,\pi_P(q)}\cdot a$ and $P_{0,\pi_P(q)} \sqsupset P_{0,q}$ by definition of $s_2$. Therefore, $P_{0,s_2}$ -- a prefix of $P$ *and* a suffix of $P_{0,q}\cdot a$ -- is *longer* than $P_{0,s_1}$, which is by definition of $s_1$ the longest prefix of $P$ that is a suffix of $P_{0,q}\cdot a$. This is a contradiction.

Before we continue with the other case, let us see that $\pi_P(q) \geq s_1 - 1$. Observe that because $P_{0,s_1} \sqsupset P_{0,q}\cdot a$, we have $P_{0,s-1} \sqsupset P_{0,q}$. Assuming that $\pi_P(q) < s_1 - 1$ immediately contradicts the maximal choice of $\pi_P(q)$ ($s_1 - 1$ is in the set $\pi_P(q)$ is chosen from).

- Assume $s_1 > s_2$. We have just shown $|P_{0,\pi_P(q)}\cdot a| \geq s_1$, and remember that $P_{0,\pi_P(q)}\cdot a \sqsupset P_{0,q} \cdot a$. Therefore, $s_1 > s_2$ contradicts the maximal choice of $s_2$ ($s_1$ is in the set $s_2$ is chosen from).

As neither $s_1 > s_2$ nor $s_2 > s_1$ can hold, we have proven that $s_1 = s_2$, q.e.d.

Comment: Can you please justify your answer for $q=m$ or $Pq+1\neq a$ ?

Comment: @SCO: What do you mean by "justify"? This is just a condition in the statement that ensures that the "longest prefix of P that is a Suffix of w" is used.